# Power of a heater

Tags: power

How to use different formulas of power ( \$\frac{V^2}{R}\$, \$V \cdot I\$, \$I^2 \cdot R\$ ) in different situations?

For example, I have a heater of 1000W which converts 220 V to power (heat) in some infrared region.  If I calculate output power using  \$V\cdot I\$, it seems okay, but when I calculate power using \$\frac{V^2}{R}\$, since there is a coil of high resistance, the output power seems surprisingly small.

May be it seems a basic question, but it confused me.

Comment: What "coil of high resistance"?

Comment: Heating element of high resistance which converts electricity to heat.

Comment: @Nishu if the heater is a resistive coil type, the resistance would change as the coil heats up. This is similar to what happens with incandescent bulbs. How are you measuring the resistance?

Comment: @AnindoGhosh :I am not measuring resistance, its just a doubt arise while i was thinking, heating element is the same in most of the heating devices, i just referred that as coil, and about change in resistance, will you tell that in detail please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's little need to calculate the power of your heater, since you have already said it's a 1000W heater.

However, to address your confusion, your choice of which to use will depend on what values you know. They will all give the same result, and they are related by Ohm's law. Here's how:

You know Ohm's law, voltage equals the product of current and resistance:

\$ E = I R \$

And you know that power is the product of voltage and current:

\$ P = E I \$

Let's say you have a resistor, and you know the voltage across it, and you want to know the power dissipated in that resistor. \$ P = E I \$, but you don't directly know \$I\$, but you can calculate it with Ohm's law:

\$ I = \frac{E}{R}\$

substituting:

\$ P = E(\frac{E}{R}) \$

which simplifies to:

\$ P = \frac{E^2}{R} \$

If you have a 1000W heater which runs at 220V, I can calculate the resistance your heater must have:

\$ 1000W = \frac{(220V)^2}{R} \$

\$ R = \frac{(220V)^2}{1000W} \$

\$ R = 48.4\Omega \$

Comment: 1000 W was its input power specifications, it's not necessary, that output power will also 1000 W, also , V across the heating element is also not necessarily 220 V. 220 V is supplying voltage.

Comment: @Nishu: it's unlikely the heater would change the voltage. It's true that some of the 1000 W of input may go to running a fan, a lamp, or a motor, but the power consumed by these components is negligible compared to the heating element, and I didn't think the extra complexity was necessary.

Comment: can u tell me order of resistance of heating elements of real life heaters( which we use in cold or for household purposes )

Comment: @Nishu: for 220V heaters, \$50\Omega\$ would be a typical value. \$1kW\$ is a good amount of heat, but not so much that it blows a household circuit breaker. The resistance of the heating element does change with temperature (resistance goes up as it gets hotter), so this calculated resistance is the resistance at operating temperature. When off, they usually look like wires.

Comment: oohhh, i read everywhere that they have high resistances, and it made me really confused. It means, resistance of heating element is relatively higher, not in kohms ?? am i right ??

Comment: @Nishu not if the element is to be used in a 220V heater. If the element was \$1k\Omega\$ at operating temperature, then: \$P=\frac{(220V)^2}{1k\Omega}\$ or \$P=48.4W\$ Not a very hot heater.

Comment: @Nishu perhaps what you were reading was describing several heating elements in parallel? This would effectively decrease their resistance, if the assembly is considered as a whole.

Comment: Are these calculations valid for the AC power that this like is? As the voltage varies from moment to moment and the power as the square of the voltage so you can't just average it out. (Not saying it's not valid, asking the question)

Comment: @JohnBurton they are valid. Volts AC are specified as an RMS average precisely so these calculations work. Things are more complated with reactive loads and the concept of [power factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_factor) comes in to play, but an electric heater is a purely resistive load for all practical purposes.

Comment: @Nishu: In this situation, "High resistance" means "higher resistance than a copper wire of the same size".

Answer (score 2):

Given Ohm's law V = I × R, and the definition of power P = I × V, you can derive a couple of other equations:

P = I<sup>2</sup> × R and P = V<sup>2</sup> / R

You can solve each of the latter two for R:

R = P / I<sup>2</sup> and R = V<sup>2</sup> / P

Since these equations are all derived from the same place, if you know any two numbers, you can calculate the other two. In this case, you know the voltage and the power. Therefore, the current is:

I = P / V = 4.545 A

And the resistance is:

R = V<sup>2</sup> / P = 48.4 Ω

No matter which equation you use to calculate power based on these numbers, you'll get 1000W.